# Having trouble understanding Function overloading

Tags: javascript

Im having a hard time grasping this example from the book "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja".

The concept is you have a addMethod function that allows you to passe multiple versions of the same method to an object, the difference being the amount of parameters those methods accept, what they process those parameters.

Im not getting the "mechanics" behind this. In the inspector I only see the first method yet somehow when I run the `find` method with different parameters it still manages to use the proper variation of it. But how? How can those methods still be available after running the `addMethod` with the three versions?
Can you help me understand this?

The function to bind the methods to the object:

```
addMethod = function(object, name, fn) {
  var old;
  old = object[name];
  return object[name] = function() {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
      return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

Then you could assign the same function name as property of an object like this:

```
addMethod(ninjas, 'find', function() {
  return this.values;
});

addMethod(ninjas, 'find', function(name) {
  var ninja, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
  _ref = this.values;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    ninja = _ref[_i];
    if (ninja.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
      _results.push(ninja);
    }
  }
  return _results;
});

addMethod(ninjas, 'find', function(first, last) {
  var ninja, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
  _ref = this.values;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    ninja = _ref[_i];
    if (ninja === ("" + first + " " + last)) {
      _results.push(ninja);
    }
  }
  return _results;
});
```

Comment: Try experimenting a bit with `fn.apply`. Try using it inside a function and return the result of `fn.apply`. Apart from that, try stepping through the code and thinking about what happens at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addMethod = function(object, name, fn) {
  var old;
  old = object[name];
  return object[name] = function() {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
      return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

Let us start:

`object[name] = function ()` assigns a function to the object.

For example:

```
ninjas["find"] = function()
```

Then it's comparing the number of arguments that were named (fn.length) to the the number of arguments passed in (arguments.length), using the 1st match. So that it can determine which function it need to call.

If the first condition doesn't satisfy then it checks for the type of older function. If it's a function, then it just applies the arguments to the older function.

`fn.length` refers to the outer  most function passed.

&

`arguments.length` refers to the arguments of inner most function length.

so how the overriding works?

As you can see each time we call `addMethod` its taking reference of the function to a variable called `old`. Then based on the `if` condition results, its overriding the previous function with the newer one.

if we don't have any older function with matching variables, it will return undefined.

For example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
function                            -       fn.length == arguments.length
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ninjas.find()                       -        (0 == 0), uses `function ()`
ninjas.find("Rias")                 -        (1 == 1), uses `function (name)`
ninjas.find("Mohamed", "Rias")      -        (2 == 2), uses `function (first, last)`
ninjas.find("Mohamed", "Rias", "A") -        (? == 3), no match, returns `undefined`
```

Answer (score 3):

Each time you overload a function, it will take the old function and replace it with a function that checks which of the overloads to use.

After adding the first function you have code that (roughly) does the same as:

```
ninjas.find = function(){
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    // code for first overload
  }
}
```

After adding the second function, you have code that does the same as:

```
ninjas.find = function(){
  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    // code for second overload
  } else {

    if (arguments.lenght === 1) {
      // code for first overload
    }

  }
}
```

Each time you add another overload, another level of checks is added around the previous code.

Comment: Thank you @Guffa, although I understand your explanation im having trouble understanding how the method `find` isn't overwritten when I call the `addMethod`.
I though the methods were being stored directly on the object but that isn't the case.

Comment: @LuisMartins: The `addMethod` gets the previos value of the property and stores in a local variable, and then replaces the property. The previous method reference only exists in the closure of the new function that is assigned to the `find` property.